# SQL Server script schema changes to other environments

Tags: sql-server, ssis, synchronization, schema

I have a development environment where we are building out an application and we are using a Microsoft SQL database. We want to be able to track the changes we make in out dev environment so that when we are ready to deploy to production, we can also generate a script to update the production database with the changes we made to the schema in dev.

Is there a tool out there will do that?

Comment: The most popular commercial tool is http://www.red-gate.com/ but there are a quite a few others. Search for "schema comparison tools" in your favourite search engine.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve your schema comparison and script genration, you can use Databse Project type from Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools which is a free offering from Microsoft - 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt

Once you download and install you can follow the steps in the following link to do the comparison -

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh272690(v=vs.103).aspx